# Convert rgb to black and white in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use Python to convert a color image into a black and white image, but I should not use the library. But opening a file with a library is allowed, but converting it to black and white should not be done with a library. I know the CV2 library does this, but I want it to do without the library.

Comment: black and white or greyscale?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this site can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") and ["How do I ask and answer homework questions?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions "How do I ask and answer homework questions?") pages for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the image can be loaded as list in with a size of [x,y,3], where the last dimension contains the 3 color bytes as separate elements.

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

raw_img = Image.open("your_image_here")
img = raw_img.load()
x,y = raw_img.size
threshold = 300
bw_img = [[0]*y]*x # blank image

for i in range(x):
  for j in range(y):
    if img[i,j] < threshold:
      bw_img[i][j] = 0
    else:
      bw_img[i][j] = 1

Image.fromarray(np.asarray(bw_img),mode=1).save("your_nwe_image.bmp")
```

An image can be treated as 2D array/list with and additional dimension for the color values of each channel RGB.
This checks for every pixel whether the sum of the color values is above a threshold, and assigns the pixel as white. How you want to determine if a pixel will be white exactly or not is up to you.

But honestly doing this without a library is not really useful, even numpy is much faster and efficient for such a task.

Comment: Can you explain more with a loaded photo example?

Comment: I was under the impression you already had the image loaded using some library? What image format do you have?

Comment: Input image must bmp

Comment: The output image is purely black

Comment: you need to adjust the threshold. I dont know your pixel values. Just try different guesses.